# Repo not found Unity Admob Plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I want to implements ads in my little android game that I am making in unity. I followed the steps here for the implementation of the admob unity plugin: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/unity/start

However, after I wrote my banner ad code, I cannot build the app anymore, because I am receiving the following errors:

```
Repo not found: C:\Android\extras\google\m2repository

Error: Unable to find dependency com.google.android.gms play-services-ads LATEST in ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\android\m2repository)
```

I went and looked into the directory and I do not have the m2repository folder. So I am guessing I have to get it from somewhere, but I do not know where.

Answer (score 0):

Install this packages in Android SDK Manager (GUI).

- Android Support Repository.
- Google Play Services
- Google Repository    (this have m2repository)